# UnitTest Project by Kentico 9 Tests not visible in Test-Explorer

Tags: unit-testing, inheritance, visual-studio-2013, nunit, kentico

I have a Problem with creating automated test project on Kentico 9.

There is a tutorial on  https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Creating+automated+test+projects

**The Problem is**: if my Test Class inherit from **CMS.Tests.UnitTests**,

my Tests are no longer visible in the Test-Explorer of my Visual Studio 2013.

If my Test Class don´t inherit from **CMS.Tests.UnitTests** I can see my tests in Test-Explorer.

I use NUnit, VisualStudio 2013 Professional, Kentico 9

[image: Without inherit from UnitTests]

[image: With the inherit from UnitTests]

**How can I make it visible ???**

Comment: Are you sure it's inheriting from CMS.Tests.UnitTests?

Comment: as you can see it on the second picture (yellow). The using is on the top.

Comment: Correct, but It could be referencing to another UnitTests class. But I assume you've checked that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by using incorrect version of NUnit.

Your test project must reference nunit.framework.dll (version 2.6.3, which is located in the Lib directory) to work properly with CMS.Tests.dll from Kentico 9.

Also you need to use NUnit test adapter for NUnit 2.0 (not the NUnit3 test adapter): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnitTestAdapter